# How to find the most common and least common numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a database which consists of 5 columns

Each column is an INT

I want to find out which numbers  occur most frequently in each column

I also wanted to know which sequence of numbers occurs more frequently

The same thing is true with the least common

I would like to use MYSQL or SQLITE

Comment: What do you mean by "*sequence of numbers*"?  Absent an explicit sort order, the order of records is undefined.

Comment: Erm, candidate for normalization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### assuming schema as follows

```
tbl(..., int_col1, int_col2, int_col3, int_col4, int_col5, ...)
```

#### most frequently

do following query for each column

```
SELECT int_col1, COUNT(int_col1)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY int_col1
ORDER BY COUNT(int_col) DESC LIMIT 1
```

#### least frequently

do following query for each column

```
SELECT int_col1, COUNT(int_col1)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY int_col1
ORDER BY COUNT(int_col) ASC LIMIT 1
```

#### sequence of numbers occurs more frequently

```
SELECT int_col1, int_col2, int_col3, int_col4, int_col5, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY int_col1, int_col2, int_col3, int_col4, int_col5
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: can't he just do a min,max on the counts for that

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady hello, are you talking about `most` and `least`? I have edited my answer.

Comment: yea that could work, but for me I would return the whole set without `LIMIT` and extract the maximum and minimum on the application level.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks, I agree with you if there are small result set. If result set is large, network cost would be higher. Let him choose proper way he wants. ;-)

Comment: Everyday a sequence of numbers are entered into the table. Today's sequence is 2, 5, 12 ,17 and 64

Comment: We want to know how often a specific sequence is repeated(the same numbers in that same order). Col1 will always have the smallest number and Col5 will always have the largest. The sequence will always be smallest to largest

Answer (score 0):

`assuming column is userid`

```
select UserID, count(UserID)
    from myUsers
    group by UserID
    order by count(UserID) desc
```

OR

```
with cte as
(
select user_id,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by UserID) as rn
)

select user_id,count(user_id) as se_count from cte group by user_id
```